# "Connection closed" occurs when executing a agent

Tags: volttron

"Connection closed" occurs when executing a function for data pre-processing.

The data pre-processing is as follows.

1. Import data points of about 30 topics from the database.( Data for 9 days every 1 minute, 
   60 * 24 * 9 * 30 = 388,800 values)
2. Convert data to a pandas dataframe for pre-processing such as missing value or resampling (this process takes the longest time)
3. Data processing

In the above data pre-processing, the following error occurs.

```
volttron.platform.vip.rmq_connection ERROR: Connection closed unexpectedly, reopening in 30 seconds.
```

This error is probably what the VOLTTRON platform does to manage the agent.

Since it takes more than 30 seconds in step 2, an error occurs and the VOLTTRON platform automatically restarts the agent.

Because of this, the agent cannot perform data processing normally.

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening during agent instantiation I would suggest moving the pre-processing out of the **init** or configuration steps to a function with the @core.receiver("onstart") decorator. This will stop the agent instantiation and configuration steps from timing out. The listener agent's on start method can be used as an example.